# jQuery selector next child of nested elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-selectors

How to select the next input within nested elements? For example: when currently selecting 1a, pressing the down arrow key should select 2x, and down again should select 3x, and so on until 6x. In the other case, if currently selecting 1a, press the right arrow key should select 1b.

html:

```
<div class='id_group'>
    <div class='id_row'>
        <div><div><input value='1a' /></div></div>
        <div><div><input value='1b' /></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class='id_row'>
        <div><div><input value='2a' /></div></div>
        <div><div><input value='2b' /></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='id_group'>
    <div class='id_row'>
        <div><div><input value='3a' /></div></div>
        <div><div><input value='3b' /></div></div>
        <div><div><input value='3c' /></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class='id_row'>
        <div><div><input value='4a' /></div></div>
        <div><div><input value='4b' /></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='id_group'>
    <div class='id_row'>
        <div><div><input value='5a' /></div></div>
        <div><div><input value='5b' /></div></div>
        <div><div><input value='5c' /></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class='id_row'>
        <div><div><input value='6a' /></div></div>
        <div><div><input value='6b' /></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('input').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.which==40)$(this).closest('.id_group, .id_row').next().find('input').focus();
    if(e.which==39)$(this).closest('.id_row').next().find('input').focus();
});
```

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq) or [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get). But `.get()` will throw errors around the boundaries so I used `.eq()`

`var inputs` stores the references of all the elements that have a keyup event attached. It will look like this 
`[input, input, input, input, input, input, input, input, input, input, input, input, input, input]`

In `inputs.index($(this))` $(this) refers to the current element that you are on and `.index` will get the position of current element from the array.

```
var inputs = $('input').keyup(function(e) {
  var index = inputs.index($(this));
  if (e.which == 40) {
    inputs.eq(index + 2).focus();
  }
  if (e.which == 39) {
    inputs.eq(index + 1).focus();
  }
  if (e.which == 38 && index > 0) {
    inputs.eq(index - 1).focus();
  }
});
```

```js
var inputs = $('input').keyup(function(e) {
  var index = inputs.index($(this));
  if (e.which == 40) {
    inputs.eq(index + 2).focus();
  }
  if (e.which == 39) {
    inputs.eq(index + 1).focus();
  }
  if (e.which == 38 && index > 0) {
    inputs.eq(index - 1).focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='id_group'>
  <div class='id_row'>
    <div>
      <div>
        <input value='1a' tabindex="1" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <input value='1b' tabindex="3" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='id_row'>
    <div>
      <div>
        <input value='2a' />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <input value='2b' />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='id_group'>
  <div class='id_row'>
    <div>
      <div>
        <input value='3a' />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <input value='3b' />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <input value='3c' />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='id_row'>
    <div>
      <div>
        <input value='4a' />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <input value='4b' />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='id_group'>
  <div class='id_row'>
    <div>
      <div>
        <input value='5a' />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <input value='5b' />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <input value='5c' />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='id_row'>
    <div>
      <div>
        <input value='6a' />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <input value='6b' />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Btw up key is `38`

Hope this helps

Comment: Even this didn't answered my question completely(right arrow key should behave what the down arrow key currently does, and down arrow key should skip 1 entirely and go to 2, then 3). Also not sure how 'inputs.' nor 'var index' works, but they works! This sure helped me to get to where I wanted. Thank you very much Dhiraj!

Comment: updated the answer. Down arrow goes at 2x down, right arrow goes at 1x down.

Comment: I purposely having "row" 3 and 5 with 3 inputs instead of uniform 2 inputs, so a simple indexing addition wouldn't exactly works. Actually I guess it works for combination of 2 and 3 inputs, since my requirements are 3x, 4x, 5x, and 6x. It wouldn't work if the combinations are 2 and 4 inputs...Thank you very much though.